# Parameter Resolvers clashing

Tags: selenium, junit5

I'm running into an issue with clashing parameter resolvers. The error I'm getting is `ParameterResolutionException: Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers for parameter [the parameter]`. This is definitely due to having a base class that extends an implementation of `ParameterResolver` so that I can grab the context to check whether the test has failed.

My code looks similar to this:

```
public class ExtensionContextResolver implements ParameterResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final ParameterContext parameterContext, final ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(final ParameterContext parameterContext, final ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return extensionContext;
    }
}

@ExtendsWith(ExtensionContextResolver.class)
public abstract class TestBase {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @AfterEach
    protected void afterEach(final ExtensionContext context) {
        // take screenshot using instance of driver in this class
}

public class MyTest extends TestBase {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(MyEnum.class)
    public void my_super_sweet_test(final MyEnum myEnum) {
        // the test
    }
}
```

What should I do to get around this issue? Is there a better way to handle failure scenarios while still being able to use field declared within the class?

Edit: changed test name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're running into comes up because your own `ExtensionContextResolver` announces to resolve any kind of object - which it actually does not. The solution is to announce the real scope in `supportParameter`:

```
class ExtensionContextResolver implements ParameterResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final ParameterContext parameterContext, final ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return parameterContext.getParameter().getType().equals(ExtensionContext.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(final ParameterContext parameterContext, final ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return extensionContext;
    }
}
```

That way the exception should no longer occur.